Probable typo in a book for the complex limit $\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+ \bar z}$
I get stuck finding the solution of this exercise: $$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+ \bar z}$$
The book says that the solution is 1, but I don't understand why. I tried to put  $z$ in polar form, i.e.
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+ \bar z} = \lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{1+\rho e^{i\theta}}{1+1 +\rho e^{-i\theta}}=\lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{1+\rho e^{i\theta}}{2 +\rho e^{-i\theta}}$$ but I don't know how to continue. The result should be 1. Any hint? thank you

$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+ \bar z} = \frac 12$

Was the question actually $\lim\limits_{z\to1}\dfrac{\color{red}2}{1+\overline z}$?

So the book has a typo? damn I spent the whole afternoon trying to solve the limit as 1...

@J.W.Tanner nope, the book says $$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+ \bar z}$$ and the result should be 1, but it could be a typo

What is the book and page number?

@J.W.Tanner Shouldn't that result be $1$?

Should be a typo as J.W. already said, but I can't help which one. My first guess was $\frac{z}{1-\overline{z}}$, but we would have $\frac{1}{0}$ then. Does your book really just give the solution $1$ and no further explanation?

@mathquester:  yes, $\lim\limits_{x\to1}\dfrac2{1+\overline z}=1$, and OP said the result should be $1$

OP: This is probably a good opportunity to build a bit of confidence in your own skills.

You do not need to write $z$ polar form. We have
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{z}{1+\bar z} = \frac{\lim_{z \to 1}z}{\lim_{z \to 1}1+\bar z} = \frac 1 2  .$$
If your book claims that the limit is $1$, then there must be a typo. If it is an older book, then the author certainly produced a handwritten manuscript which was converted into a printing template by someone else. The number "2" has probably been misread as "z". Thus the correct version should be
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{2}{1+\bar z} .$$

Thank you very much!

Set $z=1+w.$ Then $w\to 0.$ Hence we may assume that $|w|\le 1.$ Next $$\left |{z\over 1+\overline{z}}-{1\over 2}\right |=\left |{1+w\over 2+\overline{w}}-{1\over 2}\right |\\ ={|w+2\overline{w}|\over 2|2+\overline{w}|} \le {3|w|\over 2(2-|w|)}\le {3\over 2}|w|\to 0$$
